# How to open 'Amazon' app on playstore programmatically?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-package-managers

I'm trying to open Amazon app programmatically and if it is not found in the phone, the user is asked to install it from play store but the problem is that when I'm trying to open it in playstore, it is showing `Item not found` error.

Here's my code:

```
public void openApp(final String packageName, final String appName) {
        Intent intent = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
         if (intent != null) {
             startActivity(intent);
         } else {
             AlertDialog.Builder builder;
             builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
             builder.setMessage(appName + " not found. Would you like to install " + appName + " from play store?")
                     .setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                             try {
                                 startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName)));
                             } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                                 startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + packageName)));
                             }
                         }
                     })
                     .setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                         }
                     })
                     .show();
         }
    }
```

where `packageName` is `in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping` and `appName` is `Amazon`.

I've got the package name from app's playstore link, i.e., https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping&hl=en

What's going wrong here and how can I successfully open amazon app on playstore if not found in the device?

Comment: I just checked with your code & it loads the amazon app in Play store fine for me. Are you sure you are passing the same package name which you posted here? i.e in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping?. Please make sure there's no typo there.

Comment: @sam_0829 another silly mistake by me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        try {
            pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            return true;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        }

        return false;
    }
```

use this method to find an app is installed or not and then

boolean isAppInstalled = appInstalledOrNot("com.check.application");

```
    if(isAppInstalled) {
        //This intent will help you to launch if the package is already installed
        Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager()
            .getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.check.application");
        startActivity(LaunchIntent);

        Log.i("Application is already installed.");       
    } else {
        // Do whatever we want to do if application not installed
        // For example, Redirect to play store

        Log.i("Application is not currently installed.");
    }
```